# Analysing complexity/runtime of pseudocode using big-O notation

Tags: big-o, pseudocode

I need a little help with a problem. I just started reading about O-notation but I'm still new when it comes to analysing code.

So here's the problem:

The following pseudocode is given, where A is a number field whose elements over the indices 1 to length(A) can be accessed

```
1: procedure Adder(A)
2:      for i <- 1 to length(A)
3:          for j <- length(A) to 1 do 
4:              if i ≠ j then
5:                 A[i] <- A[i] + A[j]
```

Give the complexity of the following lines of code in big-O notation:

1. lines 4-5
2. lines 3-5
3. lines 2-5

So for lines 4-5 I thought it should be simply O(1) since it simply just adds 2 elements.

With the other two I'm really unsure.

For line 3-5 I think it should be O(n) where n is the number of indices in the number field.

And finally for lines 2-5 I would say it's O(n^2) since we now have to loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems correct to me, although you may want to reformulate some of the justification you have

> lines 4-5 I thought it should be simply O(1) since it simply just
>   adds 2 elements.

It is O(1) because **no matter what the input is**, the algorithm will end up doing either 1 or 2 instructions. It will never grow bigger than 1 or 2

> finally for lines 2-5 I would say it's O(n^2) since we now have to
>   loops?

It is O(n^2) because the nested loops are iterating on the sequence you have as input. No matter what happens, if the input is of length N, you will have to make N loops, and N loops inside. So you end up with N * N which is N^2 as you suggested.